# Longtable and strange behavior after the last footer

Tags: tables, longtable

Here is a compilable `.tex` file which makes use of the `longtable`. I understand that `longtable` is not strictly necessary here, however my real use case contains much more data. This is just a minimal working example I have concocted for the purposes of this question.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{4cm}|p{8cm}|}
      \caption{Relevant past projects} \\
      \hline
      Project Number & Name & Description \\
      \hline
      \endfirsthead
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- Continued from previous page} \\
      \endhead
      \multicolumn{3}{r}{Continued on next page} \\
      \endfoot
      \endlastfoot
      112038 & some project name & \multirow{3}{8cm}{Some project description} \\
      \cline{1-2}
      115274 & some other project name & \\
      \cline{1-2}
      202246 & yet another project name & \\
      \hline
      \label{tab:relevant_projects}
    \end{longtable}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this using `pdflatex`, the resulting file shows a table which has vertical lines extending beyond the last footer:

[image]

I do not understand why this occurs. Could anyone please help?

Comment: This is because you used label at the end. Use label right after the caption on the top followed by \\.

Comment: You're right. Removing `\label` fixes the problem. But why does this happen? Why does it consider `\label` to be an additional row? `\label` is a valid tex command? Is it not?

Comment: That's because the longtable environment thinks the label is an element when you give it at the bottom, This makes the longtable add another extra row which itself is incomplete. The label doesn't; display itself and is used only for reference.

Comment: Ok,  but if I use it after the caption at the top then I have a similar problem, except below the caption...

Comment: Did you use like this `\caption{caption} \label{label}`\\ ? If not then you used it incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, It is a duplicate and I found no reason to post an answer. So I hope you found your answer there.

Comment: @JohnKormylo we literally just commented about that. Please take a look at the previous comments.

Comment: I see. Thanks ...

Comment: this is unrelated to longtable you would see teh same with `tabular`.  Also but unrelated don't put `longtabl` in a `center` environmnet (it doesn't centre it, it just adds spurious vertical space)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is unrelated. How do I actually highlight \\ in the comment?  `\\\`- That's a failed attempt.

Comment: @M.A.Bromuela easy way is to put a space after the `\\ ` it is possible to get the code `\\ ` without a trailing space but I always forget how

Comment: ``\\``  well not always! @M.A.Bromuela I just remembered: backtick-bactick-backslash-backslash-backtick-backtick

Comment: ``\\`` Let's see..... That works! Though  just a little bit space. Thanks!